# How to access combobox inside control template in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a control template defined like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="fiscalItemsControlTemplate">
  <Grid Grid.Column="2">
           <Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <RowDefinition Height="17" />
               <RowDefinition Height="19" />
               <RowDefinition Height="17" />
               <RowDefinition Height="19" />
               <RowDefinition Height="17" />
               <RowDefinition Height="19" />
           </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Label Padding="0"  Grid.Row="0" Content="{DynamicResource AmmountStr}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="lblAmmount" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="17"/>
      <TextBox Padding="0"  Name="txtAmmount" Grid.Row="1" Height="19" Width="189" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Text="{Binding Path=Amount, Converter={StaticResource moneyConverter}}" />
      <Label Padding="0"  Content="PurchasePrice" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Height="17" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="lblPurchasePrice" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
      <TextBox Padding="0"  Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" Height="19" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="txtPurchasePrice" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" Text="{Binding Path=PurchasePrice, Converter={StaticResource moneyConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" Validation.Error="Validation_Error" PreviewTextInput="NumericOnly" />
      <Label Padding="0" Grid.Row="4" Name="lblOrderState" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Order State" Height="17" />
      <ComboBox Padding="0" Grid.Row="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="cbOrderState" Height="19" Width="189" >
      </ComboBox>
  </Grid>
 </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

What I'm trying to do is to access combobox "cbOrderState" in codebehind and declare it's itemssours there. I know there are some ways with the FindName() method but how to use it when control template is defined in Window.Resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CollectionViewSource:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ViewName"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

and use in your combobox:

```
<ComboBox Padding="0" Grid.Row="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="cbOrderState" Height="19" Width="189" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewName}}" >
```

and populate data in codebehind:

```
CollectionViewSource yourView = ((CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("ViewName")));

yourView.Source = yourCollection;
```

Comment: Very nice. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's not a good practise to access template and set it's properties from code behind when you have binding already to support that.

Now, even in case you want to do that **`FindName()`** is a way to go. You need to access Template from the control on which this resource is applied.

Say you have comboBox declared like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmb" Template="{StaticResource fiscalItemsControlTemplate}"/>
```

You can access from code behind like this:

```
var comboBox = cmb.Template.FindName("cbOrderState", cmb);
```